# What is the name for the portion of a number that wholly divides?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, terminology

What is the name for the operation that gives the portion of a number that wholly divides. kind of the the opposite of remainder/modulo
e.g.

```
f(10, 3) = 9
f(9, 3) = 9
f(8, 3) = 6
f(7, 3) = 6
f(6, 3) = 6
f(5, 3) = 3
```

what should i name **f**?

(`f(dividend, divisor)` would be `dividend - remainder` or `divisor * quotient`)

Comment: I cannot think of any name in common or even occasional use. The function is just $n\lfloor\frac{m}{n}\rfloor$. Why do you need to name it?

Comment: You could also calculate the result as
$$
f(n,m) = n - ({n \mod m})
$$

Comment: i wanted to name it because i'm a programmer and i needed this function. and i'd prefer to use the real maths name if there is one. at the moment it's called unremainder() and so far it looks like it's going to stay that way

Comment: largest multiple ?

Answer (score 1):

The Wolfram Language (used by *Mathematica* and [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com)) treats this as a generalization of [the `Floor` function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Floor.html):

- `Floor[x]` is the greatest integer not greater than `x`.
- `Floor[x,a]` is the greatest multiple of `a` not greater than `x`.

[Likewise](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ceiling.html), the language also offers `Ceiling[x,a]` as a generalization of `Ceiling[x]`.

Answer (score 0):

Not aware of any special name for this, but considering you are flooring to the nearest multiple of $n$, `nfloor` might be a reasonable name.